# puppeteer wait for element disappear or remove from DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

Is there any way or Puppeteer API we can wait element to disappear or remove from Dom and then continue the execution?

E.g I have a loading animation I want to wait until this loading animation remove from Dom.

Answer (score 38):

`waitForSelector` has a `hidden` option which also check if the element is in the DOM:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('div', {hidden: true});
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
await page.waitForFunction(() => !document.querySelector(querySelector));
```

Comment: `waitFor` is deprecated. You can use `waitForFunction` in its place in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If you're waiting for API response, maybe it's better to rely on

```
await page.waitForResponse(response => response.url() === myUrl && response.status() === 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use page.waitForFunction with a conditional statement.

```
await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("#myElement") === null')
```

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args